how i can connect the google looker studio to facebook ads throw api?
I'd like to connect my Facebook Ads data to both Power BI and Google Looker Studio. I was looking into using an API for this, but I haven't found a free solution. While there are several third-party connectors available online, such as Windsor, Supermetrics, Coupler.io, and Catchr, I'm hoping to find a way to achieve this without any cost.
